# django Context syntax error

Tags: python, django, syntax-error, django-1.6

I'm new to Django and try to create a simple blog, but a syntax error keeps appearing in the views.py file in the Context line. I use Django 1.6, and the syntax seems compatible with this version.
Here's the simple method from views.py, where I get the error:

```
def archive(request):
    posts = blogPost.objects.all()  
    t = loader.get_template("archive.html") 
    c = Context({'posts': })
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Here's the traceback:

```
    Environment:
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog

    Django Version: 1.6
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'blog')
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      90.                 response = middleware_method(request)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py" in process_request
      71.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
      573.         resolve(path, urlconf)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      453.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
      346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
      341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
      40.         __import__(name)
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\myblog\myblog\urls.py" in <module>
      12.   url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
      26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
      40.         __import__(name)
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\myblog\blog\urls.py" in <module>
      2. from blog.views import archive

    Exception Type: SyntaxError at /blog
    Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is invalid:

```
c = Context({'posts': })
```

There needs to be a value there:

```
c = Context({'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. Python is easy language to make stupid mistakes :)